# Основы JS почему программа завершается раньше времени?

Tags: javascript, alert

Я только начинаю изучать основы JS и по тому что уже знаю сделал простенький код. Но в случае если ничего не вводить и нажать ОК то программа закрывается вместо того чтобы продолжить работать, подскажите почему? И насколько правильный код который я написал? Это было первое что я написал сам на js.

```js
let count = 3;
let answer;

do {
 answer = prompt(`Как официально называется язык JavaScript? У вас осталось попыток: ${count}`);
 if (answer == "ECMAScript") {
  alert(`Поздравляем, "ECMAScript" это правильный ответ!`);
 } else if (answer != "ECMAScript" && count > 0) {
  count--;
 } 
  if (answer == null) {
   answer = false;
  } else if (answer == "" && count > 0) {
   alert(`Вы не ввели ответ, попробуйте снова! Осталось попыток: ${count}`);
  } else if (answer == "" && count == 0) {
   alert(`Вы не ввели ответ и у вас осталось ${count} попыток. Вы проиграли.`)
  } else if (answer != "ECMAScript" && count != 0) {
   alert(`К сожалению, ${answer} не правильный ответ. Попробуйте снова. У вас осталось попыток: ${count}`);
  } else if (answer != "ECMAScript" && count == 0) {
   alert(`Ответ ${answer} - не правильный. У вас осталось ${count} попыток. Вы проиграли.`);
  }
} while (answer != "ECMAScript" && count > 0 && answer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удали && answer в конце и все заработает. Ведь пустая строка не равна true

```
} while (answer != "ECMAScript" && count > 0);
```

А чтобы выйти из цикла, если нажимается отмена, то

```
if (answer === null) {
  break; 
}
```

//например

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё работает. И цикл завершается тоже с break :)